# data.map is not a function-Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to assign json result to array object in my component. I am getting the following error.

```
data.map is not a function
```

I have imported `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` in my service but still getting the same error.
I have used the same code to extract another set of data from another service but the code is working fine.

**ArticleDetailService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleDetailService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getArticleDetail() {
        return this.http.get('APIURL')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

**ArticleDetailsComponent.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ArticleDetailService} from '../Services/article-detail.service';
import {ArticleDetail} from './articledetails';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-article-detail',
    templateUrl: './article-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./article-detail.component.css']
})
export class ArticleDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    obj: Array<ArticleDetail> = [];

    constructor(private _sharedService: ArticleDetailService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getArticleDetailfromService();
    }

    getArticleDetailfromService() {
        this._sharedService.getArticleDetail()
            .subscribe(data => {
                    this.obj = data.map(e => {
                        return {Abstract: e.Abstract, ImageLink: e.ImageLink}
                    });
                },
                (err) => console.log(err),
                () => console.log(this.obj)
            );
    }

}
```

**ArticleDetails.ts**

```
export class ArticleDetail{
ArticleId:string;
Abstract:string;
ArticleXML:string;
UpdatedDate:string;
ImageLink:string;
SectionName:string;
}
```

Comment: Does your `response.json()` returns an array ?

Comment: yes. it is returning the data

Comment: Is it an array ?

Comment: It is the json data i am obtaining from my api

Comment: I am not about it. When you get already the `data` in the `subscribe` functions, the type is array, you you post the structure of that object?

Comment: are you asking me to give the structure of the array?

Comment: Yes, if it is an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164538/discussion-between-shubashree-ravi-and-suren-srapyan).

Comment: You should consider logging out the contents within data, as the error you are getting screams that `data` is either undefined or not an array. Array.prototype.map is a native JavaScript method that is generically available within all arrays.